# Conic bundles structure

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, schemes, projective-varieties

This question is all about paragraph $1$ of Sarkisov's article *On Conic bundle structures*. Here is a capture of the part I am interested in:

[image]

[image]

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field whose characteristic is not $2$. A regular conic is a flat map of nonsingular (projective) varieties $\pi:V\rightarrow S$ whose generic fiber is an irreducible rational curve.

Consider a regular conic $(V,S,\pi)$. I have several questions about the first part of paragraph $1.5$:

1. the author claims that $R^i\pi_*(\mathscr{O}_V(-K_V))=0$ for $i\geq1$. I can show that for $i>1$ (this is for example corollary $1.2$ in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*), but I don't know how to prove the case $i=1$.
2. The author seems to deduce from the latter that $\mathscr{E}=(R^0\pi_*(\mathscr{O}_V(-K_V)))$ is a locally free sheaf of rank three and that $\mathscr{O}_V(-K_V)$ is relatively very ample and defines an embedding of $V$ in $Proj_S(\mathscr{E})$ under which each fiber of $\pi$ is a conic in $\mathbf{P}^2_k$. Why are all these assumptions true?

Comment: What is the source [9] mentioned in the text after your first claim, and did you check the argument contained therein?

Comment: @KReise : I should have mentionned it. The author refers to Mumford's "Lectures on curves on an algebraic surface". Nonetheless, the author doesn't specify which chapter/paragraph I should refer to.

Comment: Claim 1 should be handled by the techniques [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2729796/obtain-locally-freeness-of-a-sheaf-from-direct-image-sheaf), though I'm not totally sure about all the details of claim 2 yet. (If you could find a smooth fiber for part 2, then it's a $\Bbb P^1$ and the bundle on this fiber is $\mathcal{O}(2)$, which solves rank, and ampleness should follow from some sort of fiberwise ampleness, as positive line bundles on curves are ample. I don't have a snappy answer for why it's a conic and I haven't checked everything in this parenthetical.)

Comment: @KReiser: I checked all the assumptions: the theorem you mention makes everything work.

Comment: Happy to help. You may wish to consider writing up an answer to your own question which includes the details of your checks so that future users might benefit.